# Implementing caching in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to implement caching in Azure Pipeline. I have several queries which are listed below:

1. Can I have multiple folders in the 'path' of single 'Cache' task?
2. Where does the cache get stored when someone is using a self hosted agent(Linux in my case) ?
   Can I get the path to that cache directory?
3. Similar to caching, where does the pipeline artifacts get stored when someone is using a self hosted agent? Can I get the path to that directory as well?

I read the documentations related to caching and publish Artifacts but couldn't find the answer

Comment: Why are you concerned about #2 and #3? The idea is that the caching mechanism should be transparent to you. Cached data is stored **in Azure DevOps**, not on the agent.

Answer (score 1):

For your questions:

1. ***`Can I have multiple folders in the 'path' of single 'Cache' task?`***

   No. The **`Path`** parameter on the Cache task can only receive one directory path. It can be either an absolute path or a relative path.

   If you want to cache multiple folders, you can copy them into a common parent folder, and pass the path of the parent folder to the **`Path`** parameter on the Cache task.

---

2. ***`Where does the cache get stored when someone is using a self hosted agent(Linux in my case) ? Can I get the path to that cache directory?`***

   As **`@Daniel Mann`** has clarified, the saved cache files are stored in the storages of Azure DevOps rather than the local path on agent machine.

   The subsequent pipeline runs/jobs normally can quickly access and restore the saved cache files to the user-specified path on the agent machine.

---

3. ***`Similar to caching, where does the pipeline artifacts get stored when someone is using a self hosted agent? Can I get the path to that directory as well?`***

   Similar to the answer of question **`#2`**, by default the uploaded pipeline artifacts are stored in the storages of Azure DevOps rather than the local path on agent machine.

   In the subsequent pipeline runs/jobs, you can download the artifacts to a specified path on the agent machine using the download artifacts task.

Comment: What is the meaning of this "cache files are stored in the storages of Azure DevOps"? Can I see this or is it getting stored in some microsoft servers?

Comment: @VanditAgarwal, Yes. The caches are saved in the Microsoft Azure cloud storages specifically for Azure DevOps Services. Normally, the cloud storages are in the same region (or the same [Azure geography](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/geographies/#geographies)) as your Azure DevOps organization.